# JHipster Upgrade from 6.6.0 to 7.0.1

Tags: java, jhipster

I am trying to upgrade my JHipster app from 6.6.0 to 7.0.1. Please advise based on the following error:

```
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
ERROR! This seems to be an app blueprinted project with jhipster 6.6.0 bug (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11045), you should pass --blueprints to jhipster upgrade commmand.
Error: This seems to be an app blueprinted project with jhipster 6.6.0 bug (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11045), you should pass --blueprints to jhipster upgrade commmand.
    at module.exports.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1787:11)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/upgrade/index.js:94:12)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:720:17)
    at instantiateAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:873:30)
    at Environment.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:895:12)
    at JHipsterCommand.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js:181:20)
    at JHipsterCommand.listener [as _actionHandler] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/commander/index.js:922:31)
    at JHipsterCommand._parseCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/commander/index.js:1503:14)
    at JHipsterCommand._parseCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster-command.js:81:18)
```

Thank you! Amar

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. Which command did you run to get this error, include full command line options? Which blueprints do you use? Check in .yo-rc.json if you are not sure or in package.json,

Comment: I was trying to run the ```jhipster upgrade``` command from the directory/folder above my project directory/folder; I thought that I should since I have a microservices application. However, after I ```cd <microservice-project>```, the upgrade command progressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error and message was not clear.

After spending 30 min, found that I was in wrong folder, parent folder of actual app.

To fix the issue, before executing *jhipster upgrade* command make sure your in project folder same level as jdl, .yo-rc.json file.